# Trying to use regex to extract data between the square braces in a text file

Tags: python, regex

I an trying to create a regex in python to extract the Products name and then the products between [ ]:

I have tried this :

```
(\WVulnerable\WProducts:.*?\W.(\[))
```

But it only matches up to the first `[`. Anything I try after that fails and it then will not detect.

```
"Vulnerable Products: ": [ (fixed)
    "Redhat Linux 5.1",
    "Redhat Linux 5.0",
    "Redhat Linux 4.2",
    "Redhat Linux 4.1",
    "Redhat Linux 4.0",
    "Redhat Linux 3.0.3",
    "Redhat Linux 2.1",
    "Redhat Linux 2.0",
    "Caldera OpenLinux Standard 1.2"
],
```

```
 with open("bids.json",  'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as json_file:
    data = pd.read_json(json_file)
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

    title = json_data[0]["title"]
    id = json_data[0]["id"]
    pclass = json_data[0]["class"]
    local = json_data[0]["local"]
    remote = json_data[0]["remote"]
    prod = json_data[0]["products"]

    for i in range(len(prod)):
        data = (title, id, pclass, cve, local, remote, prod[i])
        cur.execute('insert into bids values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', data)

    db_conn.commit()
    cur.close()
```

Comment: What is the input / sample input string?

Comment: Can't you read your data as JSON, and work from there?

Comment: But you're pretty clearly telling your regex to look until the first `[`... maybe you meant `\]`? https://regex101.com/r/8KpEYS/1

Comment: Note that normaly, a regex will work *per line*; you have to add a flag to have it match across multiple lines.

Comment: Since "Vulnerable Products" is not in your example text, I doubt your example regex will match anything. You may need to adjust your example.

Comment: Can you show us more code that you used to get here? It makes to most sense to operate on the *structured data* than to try to extract data from a string.

Comment: This is json, i am trying to create entries for a sqlite3 db file, when i try to change the \[ to \] it does not find the string at all.

Comment: If it's JSON, parse it as JSON. You could then separate out e.g., dictionary keys and list items, and apply a regex or simple (partial) string comparison to those. Don't attempt to parse all of the JSON text with a single regex; that'll be too complicated 99 out of 100 times.

Comment: I have been able to get to the code portion yet, im still working through the regex.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is: your code doesn't show any use of the regex, and, from a quick glance, appears to work just fine: you are able to find all the individual products in the list. What do you still need a regex for?

Answer (score 0):

If it's JSON, parse it as JSON. You could then separate out e.g., dictionary keys and list items, and apply a regex or simple (partial) string comparison to those. Don't attempt to parse all of the JSON text with a single regex; that'll be too complicated 99 out of 100 times. – 0 0 43 mins ago

that solved it, i removed the regex before the for statement it seems to work now im getting a different error.

thank you 0 0